# How can I create the undirect Edge in OrientDB 2.2

Tags: orientdb

I am a newbie in OrientDB. Currently I want to create the undirect Edge between 2 Vertexes, it looks like: Product A relates to Product B.

I am using Java API, blueprint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aVertex.addEdge(endVertex, "label")

graph.addEdge(id, outVertex, inVertex, "label")

Either way, there are always an out and an in vertex

Comment: If you don't mind to accept the answer as good, that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create an undirected edges. In OrientDB, as in most graph databases in the market, edges always have a direction.

It is not a limitation, because you can traverse edges regardless their direction, using `both()` query operator or, in Java:

```
vertex.getEdges(Direction.BOTH, label)
```